# URL Malformed exception in Selenium WebDriver using Java to find the broken links

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, broken-links

I am using this code in Selenium script to find the broken links. So this is the code I have written but on running I am getting the malformed exception.

```
public void countNoOfLinksInHomePage(WebDriver fd) throws IOException{
        List<WebElement> listOfElements=fd.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
        //System.out.println(listOfElements.get(0));
        //log.info("name of links is " +listOfElements);
        int countOfElements=listOfElements.size();
        log.info("Total no of links in Homepage is:: " +countOfElements);

        //for(int i=0;i<countOfElements;i++){

            int responseCode=getResponseCode(listOfElements.get(1).getAttribute("href"));
            log.info("Response code of element at index 1 is:: " + responseCode);

            //break;
        //}
    }

    public static int getResponseCode(String url) throws MalformedURLException, IOException{

        URL u=new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection huc=(HttpURLConnection)u.openConnection();
        huc.setRequestMethod("GET");
        huc.connect();
        return huc.getResponseCode();
    }
```

The testng trace is :

java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: javascript

Comment: What is the input string that causes the exception to be thrown?

Comment: javascript:(function()%7Bvar%20doc=top.document;var%20bodyElement=document.body;doc.vtigerURL%20=%22http://localhost:8888/%22;var%20scriptElement=document.createElement(%22script%22);scriptElement.type=%22text/javascript%22;scriptElement.src=doc.vtigerURL+%22modules/Emails/GmailBookmarkletTrigger.js%22;bodyElement.appendChild(scriptElement);%7D)();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The page contains anchors with a javascript href:

```
<a href="javascript:..."
```

It does not make sense to test these links, therefore filter them as below code snippet:

```
String href = listOfElements.get(1).getAttribute("href");
if ((href != null) && !href.startsWith("javascript")) {
    int responseCode=getResponseCode(href);
    log.info("Response code of element at index 1 is:: " + responseCode);
}
```